# Create Dataframe based on one column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if this is a repeat question, I searched SO for awhile and, as simple as a question that it is, I couldn't find a similar one. I am looking to simply create one data frame (5x3 in my case) based off of one column in my Pandas dataframe. I've tried both pd.DataFrame and pd.concat and neither have seemed to work. Example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])

#using pd.DataFrame
table_data = {'Column1': df.iloc[0:5,0],
                 'Column2': df.iloc[5:10,0],
                 'Column3': df.iloc[10:15,0]}
pd.DataFrame(table_data)

#different method using pd.DataFrame
pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[0:5,0],
              df.iloc[5:10,0],
              df.iloc[10:15,0]],
            columns = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])

#using pd.concat
pd.concat([df.iloc[0:5,0], df.iloc[5:10,0], df.iloc[10:15,0]],
          axis=1, keys=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
```

Note that my actual starting data frame has more than just 1 column. The issues seem to be happening when I use indexing as opposed to simply hard coding the numbers that should be in each column. This seems like such a simple thing to do yet I can't seem to find anywhere how to solve it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,0].reshape(-1,5).T, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])`.

Comment: Thanks, though if I try using reshape() I get 'reshape is not defined'

Comment: My mistake, `df.iloc[:,0].values.reshape(-1,5)`

Comment: Works perfect, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
In [591]: import numpy as np
In [585]: d = pd.DataFrame()
In [553]: df_split = np.array_split(df, 5) ## Split df into equal parts of 5 rows each

In [586]: for i in df_split: 
     ...:     d = pd.concat([d,i.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1) 
     ...:

In [588]: d.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']                                                                                                                                                              

In [589]: d                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[589]: 
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1     6    11
1     2     7    12
2     3     8    13
3     4     9    14
4     5    10    15
```